# "unable to enumerate USB device" when enabled IUMMO/VT-d in BIOS

Tags: 14.04, virtualization

I am trying to get started with IUMMO feature, but when i turn it on, i cannot load my system anymore; in recovery mode i see bunch of similar error messages, ending with:

```
[ 169.00000] usb 8-3: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[ 170.00000] usb usb8-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

And then PC stops to respond. If i reconnect keyboard it repeats "detection" and stops again.

While nothing except mouse and keyboard connected. Disabling IUMMO in BIOS fixes problem and then i can start Ubuntu.

My computer specs:

```
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
    Product Name: M5A99X EVO
    Version: Rev 1.xx

GPU 1/1: GeForce GTX 580
Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8150 (IUMMO supported..)
```

Searching the Internets did not show anything, what i am missing?

Comment: Did you try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2114055&page=2&p=12851570#post12851570 ?

Comment: Seems like "soft" just disables it, now i am able to run Ubuntu with enabled IUMMO in BIOS, but `dmesg|grep IOMMU` gives me `[   31.155023] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)` Maybe i am wrong but this is bad

Comment: I can't really comment on that, sorry. From what I gather by googling, IUMMO support appears to be buggy at best.